# Display data that i just inserted in the database

Tags: php

I was coding a auth in PHP and C++ but PHP is what I need help with so here is the code inserting the data:

```
$c_con->query("INSERT INTO keys(key, days, used) VALUES ('".strtoupper(c_security::random_string(22))."', '".c_security::anti_sql_string($_POST["daysammount"])."', '0')");
```

Now I wanted to display the data that I just inserted in the database any help?

I've also tried:

```
echo strtoupper(c_security::random_string(22))
```

Comment: You'd have to query the data after adding it to the database... a second call to `random_string` will of course generate a new one

Comment: Do not build the SQL queries with variables by hand, this can lead to SQL injections. Use prepared statements instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the string in a variable before you insert it:

```
$myString = strtoupper(c_security::random_string(22));
$c_con->query("INSERT INTO keys(key, days, used) VALUES ('$myString', '".c_security::anti_sql_string($_POST["daysammount"])."', '0')");
```

Then you can use it later in your script:

```
echo $myString;
```

Or if you want to write less:

```
$c_con->query("INSERT INTO keys(key, days, used) VALUES ('".($myString = strtoupper(c_security::random_string(22)))."', '".c_security::anti_sql_string($_POST["daysammount"])."', '0')");

echo $myString;
```